# JS Why is the integer variable being reset to initial value but the array variable not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, scope, graph-algorithm

Given an input of a matrix/graph/multidimensional array (not really sure if these have unique definitions in programming), the function below is supposed to output the size of the biggest island. Land is represented by 1s and water is represented by 0s and two areas with land are only connected when they are adjacent horizontally or vertically (not diagonally).

The algorithm below works, but only when I save all islands in an array is the "islands" variable and then return the largest value saved.

Originally, I was attempting to only keep track of the size of the largest value with the "biggest" variable. However, for some reason it keeps being reset to the initial value of 0.

Why is this happening? I'm particularly confused as to why this could be happening to the "biggest" variable but not the "islands" variable since the two seem to have the exact same scope.

```
const bigIsland = matrix => {
  let biggest = 0
  let islands = []
  let visited = matrix.map(row => row.map(node => false))
  for(let y=0; y<matrix.length; y++){
    for(let x=0; x<matrix[y].length; x++){
      if (visited[y][x]) continue
      checkIsland(matrix, visited, y, x, islands, biggest)
    }
  }
  return Math.max(...islands)
}

const checkIsland = (matrix, visited, y, x, islands, biggest) => {
  console.log("biggestStart", biggest)
  console.log("islandsStart", islands)
  let currIsland = 0
  let nodesToCheck = [[y,x]]
  while(nodesToCheck.length){
    const [y, x] = nodesToCheck.pop()
    if (visited[y][x]) continue
    visited[y][x] = true
    if (matrix[y][x]===0) continue
    currIsland++
    console.log("currIsland", currIsland)
    getValidNeighbors(matrix, visited, y, x, nodesToCheck)

  }
  if (currIsland > biggest) biggest = currIsland
  if (currIsland > 0) islands.push(currIsland)
  console.log("biggest", biggest)
  console.log("islands", islands)
}

const getValidNeighbors = (matrix, visited, y, x, nodesToCheck) => {
  if(y>0) nodesToCheck.push([y-1, x])
  if(y<matrix.length-1) nodesToCheck.push([y+1, x])
  if(x>0) nodesToCheck.push([y, x-1])
  if(x<matrix[y].length-1) nodesToCheck.push([y, x+1])
}

bigIsland([ [1, 0, 1], 
            [1, 0, 1], 
            [1, 0, 0] ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a primitive variable to a function (such as `biggest` to `checkIsland`), *nothing* in that function can change the original reference to that variable in the calling function. In order to change `biggest` in `bigIsland`, you need to explicitly return the found `biggest` from `checkIsland`:

```js
const bigIsland = matrix => {
  let biggest = 0
  let islands = []
  let visited = matrix.map(row => row.map(node => false))
  for(let y=0; y<matrix.length; y++){
    for(let x=0; x<matrix[y].length; x++){
      if (visited[y][x]) continue
      biggest = checkIsland(matrix, visited, y, x, islands, biggest)
    }
  }
  return Math.max(...islands)
}

const checkIsland = (matrix, visited, y, x, islands, biggest) => {
  console.log("biggestStart", biggest)
  console.log("islandsStart", islands)
  let currIsland = 0
  let nodesToCheck = [[y,x]]
  while(nodesToCheck.length){
    const [y, x] = nodesToCheck.pop()
    if (visited[y][x]) continue
    visited[y][x] = true
    if (matrix[y][x]===0) continue
    currIsland++
    console.log("currIsland", currIsland)
    getValidNeighbors(matrix, visited, y, x, nodesToCheck)

  }
  if (currIsland > biggest) biggest = currIsland
  if (currIsland > 0) islands.push(currIsland)
  console.log("biggest", biggest)
  console.log("islands", islands)
  return biggest;
}

const getValidNeighbors = (matrix, visited, y, x, nodesToCheck) => {
  if(y>0) nodesToCheck.push([y-1, x])
  if(y<matrix.length-1) nodesToCheck.push([y+1, x])
  if(x>0) nodesToCheck.push([y, x-1])
  if(x<matrix[y].length-1) nodesToCheck.push([y, x+1])
}

bigIsland([ [1, 0, 1], 
            [1, 0, 1], 
            [1, 0, 0] ])
```

When you pass `islands`, on the other hand, `islands` is an *array*, which is an object (non-primitive), so when `islands` gets mutated inside of `checkIsland`, its changes will be visible everywhere else as well. Variables referencing non-primitives are essentially references to *the memory location of the object in memory* - objects doesn't get copied when passed, unless you do so explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `biggest` in the function `bigIsland` is independent of the variable `biggest` in `checkIsland`. Altering the variable in one function has no effect on the other. Arrays are different because when you pass an array you get a reference to the same array in the variable. Consider:

```js
function one() {
  let variable = 0;
  console.log("variable in on before calling two ", variable)

  two(variable)
  console.log("variable in on after calling two ", variable)
}

function two(variable) {
  variable += 200
  console.log("variable in two", variable)
}

one()
```

If you want both functions to alter the same variable you can put the variable in a scope both can see:

```js
let variable = 0
function one(){
    console.log("variable in on before calling two ", variable)

    two()
    console.log("variable in on after calling two ", variable)
}

function two() {
    variable += 200
    console.log("variable in two", variable)
}

one()
```

Or you can pass it as an object, which is a pretty standard way of passing things around:

```js
function one() {
  let obj = {variable: 0}
  console.log("variable in on before calling two ", obj.variable)

  two(obj)
  console.log("variable in on after calling two ", obj.variable)
}

function two(obj) {
  // notice we are not reassigning the variable obj with obj = 200
  //  but changing the thing obj refers to
  obj.variable += 200
  console.log("variable in two", obj.variable)
}

one()
```